# Convert HEX color to float color for BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker method

Tags: java, android, colors, hex

I try set color to google map icon in android:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(60.0F));
```

But I have colors in HEX like this - #ff0000 (RED)
How can I convert this HEX color to float value?

**!!!I not need PARSE HEX TO INTEGER!!!**

I need convert Color in HEX to Color in float:

[defaultMarker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html#defaultMarker(float))

```
public static BitmapDescriptor defaultMarker (float hue)
```

> The hue of the marker. Value must be greater or equal to 0 and less
>   than 360.

Comment: see this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551938/convert-hexidecimal-colors-to-floats

Comment: I eddit my question